# Terminal window scrollback buffer using screen utility

Tags: linux, unix, display, terminal

I am used to using screen on UNIX (AIX/Solaris) at work. I've installed it on my two home boxes running Ubuntu and Debian. The only difference I notice is that when I scroll up in the terminal window with my mouse, the last line in the buffer is from when I launched screen. On UNIX, I can scroll up however many lines I have set as the scrollback size in my terminal.

I know there is a built in key to scroll back up within screen itself, but I've never had to use that before. I've played around with screen buffer size parameters to no avail.
Hopefully I've worded the question coherently enough to make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [using the scrollwheel in gnu screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359109/using-the-scrollwheel-in-gnu-screen):

Basically you need something like this in your `.screenrc`:

```
termcapinfo xterm* ti@:te@
```

or set `TERM=vt100` before running screen.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was having a very hard time at figuring out what the difference was. Just realize my TERM is set to vt100 on UNIX and xterm on Linux. Thanks! Setting it to vt100 worked.

Answer (score 0):

`screen` has its own scroll buffer, independent of the terminal program; useful when more than one window is used.

While I doubt this is the only way to access the buffer, it's one way to effectively scroll back:

  ```
   ^A [  -- starts 'copy' mode, allowing cursor keys, pg up/dn/home/end to scroll back 
   ^V  -- aborts 'copy' mode, returns to normal screen function.  ^A not required.
  ```